# Integer operation with boundary when overflow in Rust

Tags: rust, integer-overflow, panic

The problem I recently meet requires to do integer operation with boundary based on the bits of integer type.

For example, using `i32` integer to do `add` operation, here's a piece of pseudo code to present the idea:

```
sum = a + b
max(min(sum, 2147483647), -2147483648)

// if the sum is larger than 2147483647, then return 2147483647.
// if the sum is smaller than -2147483648, then return -2147483648.
```

To achieve this, I naively wrote following ugly code:

```rust
fn i32_add_handling_by_casting(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    let sum: i32;
    if (a as i64 + b as i64) > 2147483647 as i64 {
        sum = 2147483647;
    } else if (a as i64 + b as i64) < -2147483648 as i64 {
        sum = -2147483648;
    } else {
        sum = a + b;
    }
    sum
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", i32_add_handling_by_casting(2147483647, 1));
    println!("{:?}", i32_add_handling_by_casting(-2147483648, -1));
}
```

The code works well; but my six sense told me that using **type casting** is problematic. Thus, I tried to use traditional panic (exception) handling to deal with this...but I stuck with below code (the panic result can't detect underflow or overflow):

```rust
use std::panic;

fn i32_add_handling_by_panic(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    let sum: i32;
    let result = panic::catch_unwind(|| {a + b}).ok();
    match result {
        Some(result) => { sum = result },
        None => { sum = ? }                                                              
    }
    sum
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", i32_add_handling_by_panic(2147483647, 1));
    println!("{:?}", i32_add_handling_by_panic(-2147483648, -1));
}
```

To sum up, I have 3 questions:

1. Is my type casting solution valid for strong typing language? (If possible, I need the explanation why it's valid or not valid.)
2. Is there other better way to deal with this problem?
3. Could panic handle different exception separately?

Comment: Are you aware of [`saturating_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.saturating_add)?

Comment: Catching panic is probably a bad idea for performance reasons. Rust panics are not designed to be used as business exceptions and should be caught very rarely, if ever. Also, casting here is a mere conversion, which is both safe and well-defined, and there is nothing wrong with using it. It's the casts between pointers of different types that are dangerous, and those aren't even possible to dereference in safe Rust.

Comment: @L.F.  Thanks. I wasn't aware the series of saturating functions in primitive type. The one is exact what I need. I'll learn the implementation by tracing the source code later.

Comment: Type casting with `as` can be problematic because it can change the value. The fix for that is to use a conversion that doesn't change the value: `From`. For example, write the first condition as ``if i64::from(a) + i64::from(b) > i64::from(i32::MAX)``. (That is, if it weren't obviously easier just to use saturating arithmetic.)

Comment: @trentcl Thanks. `From` is another new knowledge for me. If you don't mind, could you provide an example that the value is changed after `as` type casting?

Comment: Any time the value doesn't fit in the type being casted to. For example, `-10_i32 as u32` is `4294967286`, and `1_000_000_000 as i16` is `-13824`. If you happen to get the width or signedness wrong, you may just silently get the wrong value. `From` does not have this problem because integers only implement `From` when the conversion is lossless. (For conversions that are fallible, you may want to use `TryFrom`, which returns a `Result` that you can deal with in whatever way seems appropriate.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case, the Rust standard library has a method called [`saturating_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.saturating_add), which supports your use case:

```
assert_eq!(10_i32.saturating_add(20), 30);
assert_eq!(i32::MIN.saturating_add(-1), i32::MIN);
assert_eq!(i32::MAX.saturating_add(1), i32::MAX);
```

Internally, it is implemented as a [compiler intrinsic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/fn.saturating_add.html).

---

In general, such problems are not intended to be solved with panics and unwinding, which are intended for cleanup in exceptional cases only.  A hand-written version might involve type casting, but calculating `a as i64 + b as i64` only once.  Alternatively, here's a version using [`checked_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.checked_add), which returns `None` rather than panics in case of overflow:

```
fn saturating_add(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    if let Some(sum) = a.checked_add(b) {
        sum
    } else if a < 0 {
        i32::MIN
    } else {
        i32::MAX
    }
}
```